# How do you stay consistent when casing function names?

Tags: coldfusion, naming-conventions, case

I've been using CFScript for a while now, and I love it. One of the things I come across frequently is inconsistent casing of function names:

```
foo = new Query();
foo = new query();
foo.setSQL();
foo.SetSql();
ArrayAppend();
arrayAppend();
if();
If();
```

How do you stay consistent? Do use different casing for UDFs as opposed to built in functions? What is considered best practice?

Comment: Simple answer is I don't. Used to be Sean Corfield had a good CF code standards doc, but looks like it's disappeared from the interwebs. My personal favorite is Python's standards, many of which are applicable to CF: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Adobe examples use `UpperCamelCase` (but they can be inconsistent!) but we've adopted a standard that mirrors the Java standard when it comes to case of variables, functions and CFC (class) names - examples:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

and

http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Naming Conventions

We find it works well and it means using `lowerCamelCase` names for functions.

Everyone will have a different take on this, **but the important thing is to pick a standard and be consistent**.

Answer (score 2):

I like CamelCase with the first letter capitalized.

I don't distinguish between UDFs and built in functions in how I name/case them. If it really mattered (can't think of many examples), I would consider naming the function such that it was obvious.

You could also store them in a different scope, like UDF.FunctionName().

I think we once wrote a UDF that had a similar name to a built in function, but it was just for a specific project. We ended up naming the function name with a short project-specific prefix: C3StringWrap(). Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I always camelcase with the first letter capital (ArrayAppend, not arrayAppend). In practice it doesn't matter, but I'm a bit OCD about it all :).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is most common to name functions (UDFs and built-in) using camelCase with the first letter lowercase.

This is the standard used by ColdFusion Builder with code assist for built-in functions. This was also the recommendation in [Adobe's ColdFusion Coding Guidelines](http://livedocs.adobe.com/wtg/public/coding_standards/style.html) document the which seems to have disappeared.